# How to structure Python package (?) to add files to individual modules

Tags: python, module, package

I am new to the Python module/package building industry. I have some methods in some files in some directory. Let's assume it looks like this:

```
MyOps/
|--FileOperations.py
|--DirectoryOperations.py
|--StringOperations.py
|--__init__.py
```

Each `*.py` file contains numerous methods and putting them all together would not be advisable from a semantic perspective. From outside the directory, I can simply use the modules as such (e.g. from a file `ops.py` that is the sister of `MyOps/`):

```
from MyOps import DirectoryOperations
DirectoryOperations.delete_tree("my/path")
```

In practice this works just fine. However, I would like to add README files for each of the modules separately (and possibly add module specific files for the respective module). I had expected that it was possible to change the directory structure as follows:

```
MyOps/
|--FileOperations/
|  |--FileOperations.py
|  |--README.md
|  |--__init__.py
|--DirectoryOperations/
|  |--DirectoryOperations.py
|  |--README.md
|  |--__init__.py
|--StringOperations/
|  |--StringOperations.py
|  |--README.md
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--examples/
|     |--...
|--__init__.py
```

However, when I try the import statement from above I get an error:

```
module 'MyOps.DirectoryOperations' has no attribute 'delete_tree'
```

I am a bit confused whether I am completely structuring my project in the wrong way, or if there's just a small detail that I'm missing. What am I doing wrong here? I am desperately looking for an example on how to structure a package with subdirectories for your modules. I tried looking up default modules but they apparently don't come with a readme-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to turn what are currently submodules into subpackages.

Your attempt to solve the problem got the structure almost right, but what used to be `MyOps.FileOperations` is now `MyOps.FileOperations.FileOperations`, which is almost certainly not what you want.

I presume that the `__init__.py` files you have created are empty. If so, simply delete them, and rename the other file in the subdirectory to `__init__.py`.

When Python initialises a module, it runs the code in the module's `.py` file. To initialise a package, however, it runs the code in the package's `__init__.py` file, so (for example) a function `f` defined in the file `MyOps/FileOperations/__init__.py` can be imported from `MyOps.FileOperations`, or you can continue to import the `FileOperations` subpackage and use functions from that as attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is what I want to do *odd*? Is there a better, more logical, or more Pythonic way to achieve something similar, where modules have their own place to live in a directory structure with additional files, examples, and so on?

Comment: That could be the subject of endless debate. For example, there are opinions about what should be delivered with software (do you include tests, etc.?). The Packaging SIG have discussed these topics at great length, and have provided ways to distribute packages and related data. This is made more complex by the differing needs of differing operations systems. Look for `setuptools` to investigate further.